# Update xml node value on android sdcard

Tags: android, xml, updates

Hi I have an android application which updates a node value. Xml file exists on sdcard and I am trying to read and update the xml file.

I am using below code.

```
private void SaveToXml() {

    String destFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/file.xml";
    try {

        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = (Document) docBuilder.parse(destFile);

        Node path = doc.getElementsByTagName("path").item(0);
        path.setNodeValue(txtPath.getText().toString());

        TransformerFactory transFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer trans = transFactory.newTransformer();
        trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(destFile));
        trans.transform(source, result);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But the thing is nothing is changing. Node value remains still.
Anything usefull ideas will be appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long hours of searching for answer the solution to this problem is so emberassing.
I used 
    path.setNodeValue(txtPath.getText().toString());
to change the node value but in that case using simply just
    path.setTextContent(txtPath.getText().toString());
(changing setNodeValue to setTextContent) is enough.